# Copy AMI from one region to another then not able to ssh to new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am stuck in a problem. I don't know why I am getting this issue.

**Problem:** I am not able to connect with the EC2 Instance.

Error:

> ubuntu@52.68.107.240: Permission denied (publickey).

Steps that I followed:

1. Take an Image (AMI) of EC2 instance from one region.
2. Copy that AMI to another region.
3. Create instance from that AMI.
4. Not able to connect with instance.

Details:

- .pem file permission is checked and it is 400
- Check Security Group port 22 is open publicly
- Try to connect with the different user like root,ec2-user

Detail error is:

```
    C:\Users\Downloads>ssh -vvv -i "TravelExpenseStaging.pem" ubuntu@52.68.107.240
    OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/.ssh/config error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 52.68.107.240 is address
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 52.68.107.240 [52.68.107.240] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Downloads/TravelExpenseStaging.pem.pub error:2
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file TravelExpenseStaging.pem type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Downloads/TravelExpenseStaging.pem-cert error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Downloads/TravelExpenseStaging.pem-cert.pub error:2
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file TravelExpenseStaging.pem-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to 52.68.107.240:22 as 'ubuntu'
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\.ssh/known_hosts:40
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.68.107.240
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    debug3: send packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: receive packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none
    debug2: compression stoc: none
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DeWCbinMU6jlkLo2NTRWyH+0aOIUNa3ilKRB5rTcND8
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\.ssh/known_hosts:40
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.68.107.240
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
    debug1: Host '52.68.107.240' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\.ssh/known_hosts:40
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
    debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
    debug2: key: TravelExpenseStaging.pem (0000000000000000), explicit
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: TravelExpenseStaging.pem
    debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:t6QUIA831kHLEb2u9d2x0lkNI2Yv4htgpnCFNd3PbgA
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    ubuntu@52.68.107.240: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a public file(using putty) to your Source instance pem file and import this file to your destination region key pair and while you launch the instance from AMI then use that key pair.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that you are using the incorrect keypair.

Please note that when a new instance is launched from an Amazon-supplied AMI, there is code to copy the nominated keypair to the `authorized_keys` file. The keypair that is copied is the one chosen when you launched in the instance.

Therefore:

- Either:

  - Create a new keypair in the target region, *or*
  - Import your existing keypair into the region
- Launch the instance again from the AMI, specifying the new keypair